# upload a remote file to google drive

Tags: file-upload, remote-server, google-drive-api

I wonder if it is possible to upload remote files directly to google drive?(remote file:a file that is not located in same server as php script)

If our file exists on http://www.example.com/path/to/file i want it to be uploaded directly(without downloading to my own server and upload later) to google drive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible directly right now. However there are some services like SMEStorage which helps you to remote upload via certain servers. This service doesn't support every file hosting. They mainly support Cloud Services.